# Phonegap FileTransfer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, upload, cordova

I am using phonegap & jquery to develop a simple iphone app.
I am trying to upload images from my iphone to my remote server.

I tried to do it using phonegap [FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)  but nothing actually happens.
Neither the success nor the error callbacks are being called.
I even tried Copy/Paste the the example in the above link with the same results.
No callback is being called and of course, nothing is uploaded to the server.
There wasn't even a request sent to the server.

Any ideas or recommended workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the sample from docs you will most probably need to change the link to PhoneGap.js to include the version number of PhoneGap you have downloaded.